# Infinite loop for testing shell script code

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to test my code for my assignment, but I keep running into this issue

```
floor=54
ceiling=116
num=0
while [ $num -ne 100 ]
num=0
do
  while [ $num -le $floor ] 
  do
    num=$RANDOM
    let "num %= $ceiling"
  done
echo $num
done
```

As you can see from the inner loop, the goal is to generate a random number in `[55, 155]` range. What's inside the outer loop and outside of the inner loop is all just there for testing the actual code. Now I want to check if my original loop can generate both `55` and `155`. I tried testing with `100`, because my original test with `55` just went on and on, and 100 is an easier number to spot to see if the outer loop works. It doesn't. I've spotted `100`, but the outer loop keeps generating more numbers.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Don't ask your homework questions here...

Comment: `num=$(((${RANDOM} + 54) % 116))` do what you need.

Comment: I didn't. I asked for testing my homework.

Answer (score 0):

You put your `num=0` in the condition of the `while` loop (i.e., before the `do`. That means the test is pretty much ignored, and since `num=0` always succeeds, the exit status of your condition is always 0, leading to the infinite loop. You want

```
while [ "$num" -ne 100 ]
do
    num=0
    ...
```

It's a subtle bug, partly caused by the fact that the condition can be an arbitrary list of commands. It's one reason I like to put the `do` on the same line as `while`:

```
while [ "$num" -ne 100 ]; do
    num=0
```

which makes it harder to think you included `num=0` in the condition than if you wrote

```
while [ "$num" -ne 100; num=0; do
    ...
```